# Why does python urllib.request.urlopen() fail when there is a double quote in the POSTed data?

Tags: python, json, post, urllib

I am trying to use urllib.request.urlopen() to POST and what I have works perfectly unless there is a double quote in the data.  I am using urllib.parse.urlencode() and bytes() before calling urlopen().  What else do I need to do?  Here is the function:

```
def getHypotheses(server, lang, dym, query):
    param = urllib.parse.urlencode({"query": query, "count": "10"})
    param_data = bytes(param,"utf-8")
    url = "%s/aqs/%s/%s" % (server, lang, dym)
    print ('query = ', query)
    try:
        connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, param_data)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        print ('param = ', param)
        print ('url = ', url, ', query = ', query, ',
                param_data = ', param_data)
        sys.exit()
    response = connection.read().decode('utf-8')
    jsonobj = json.loads(response)
    return jsonobj
```

and a sample of the output:

```
query =  IHBK
query =  B;NS
query =  ASI
query =  MDN
query =  "CMANI
param =  count=10&query=%22CMANI
url =  http://localhost:8080/myserver/aqs/foo/bar ,
       query =  "CMANI , param_data =  b'count=10&query=%22CMANI'
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!  -- Dave

Comment: A quote character `"` is not valid within a URL. Instead it needs to be URL encoded. Looks like python has a function for it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: When you speak of URL encoding the string, are you talking about a step in addition to param = urllib.parse.urlencode({"query": query, "count": "10"})?